# How do I open a shortcut that exists in a folder?

Tags: .desktop, shortcuts

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have a question, how do I use a shortcut in a folder?

I used to use windows and have dual-booted Ubuntu to keep all my files but still have Ubuntu. I downloaded the iso of 18.04 LTS first and upgraded to 20.04, but this is a clean install from iso now.

Any help would be appreciated! BTW I have the stable release.

By shortcut I mean a `.desktop` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107219/discussion-between-user-dz-and-sambhav-surana).